# How to remove empty line in excel cell with help of VBA

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I want to remove empty line in excel cell with help of VBA and it could n't disturb the values in cells

Comment: Please add more detail such as a screenshot or sample data so we can assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following VBA code should do what you need in Excel. Before testing, be sure to work from a copy of your spreadsheet in case anything goes wrong.

```
Sub RemoveEmptyRows()

Dim Rw As Range
With Application

        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        '.ScreenUpdating = False

    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
        For Each Rw In Selection.Rows

            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rw.EntireRow) = 0 Then

                Rw.EntireRow.Delete
                count = count + 1

            End If

        Next Rw

        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

        '.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

*Note that if you expect a large number of rows to be deleted, uncommenting the '.ScreenUpdate = False/True' lines can speed up the deletion process.*

Algorithm:

- Disable formula calculation during deletion. (.Calculation=xlCalculationManual)
- Select the active range containing blank cells in the current worksheet. (SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select)
- Loop through each row. (For Each)
- Delete the entire row if none of the cells in the row contain data. (CountA function)
- Enable formula calculation to refresh values. (.Calculation=xlCalculationAutomatic)